# Help in Expression Reading in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, notation

I am reading a paper on TSP. The paragraph goes as follows:

[image]

I am trying to understnd what does the last expression mean and how to read it. So to break it down, what does $V\setminus \{1,n\}$  mean? How to read it out in english?

Comment: \setminus ($\setminus$) is [set difference (aka: relative complement)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)): set $V$ from which the elements $1$ and $n$ have been subtracted.

Comment: $n$ is the number of elements of $V$ : $n= |V|$, where $V$ is the set of *nodes*. Thus $i \in V \setminus \{ 1, n \}$ means simply : $i=2,3,\ldots, n-1$.

Comment: This makes sense, I have a additional small question though. The service time $s_i$ is exclusive of the maximum time I can arrive at the scene $b_i$? So I think then it will make sense to have total time as the addition as shown in the expression. Right?